# TikZ figure always positioned at the center of a new page

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, positioning, lncs

I run into this rather strange problem when using TikZ with LyX 2. I have this graph programmed using TikZ, and it is supposed to follow a paragraph of text and be positioned at the top of next new page. Instead, it is positioned exactly at the center of the new page, leaving a chunk of space between the text and itself. In my document, I place the tex code for the figure immediately after the text itself with a space, and the TikZ code is as follows.

```
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{figure}[ht!]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture} [label distance=2mm,
        vertice/.style={circle, fill=gray!30, thick, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=7mm},
        dot/.style={shape=circle, fill=black, minimum size=2pt, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=2pt}]
        \node [vertice] (a) at (0,7) {$t_1$};
        \node [vertice] (b) at (0,6) {$t_2$};
        \node [vertice] (c) at (0,5) {$t_3$};
        \node [dot] (d) at ($(c) + (270:1)$) {};
        \node [dot] (e) at ($(d) + (270:0.5)$) {};
        \node [dot] (f) at ($(e) + (270:0.5)$) {};
        \node[draw, ellipse, label=below:$T$, fit=(a) (b) (c) (d) (e) (f)] {};\node [vertice] (h) at (5,7) {$a_1$};
        \node [vertice] (i) at (5,6) {$a_2$};
        \node [vertice] (j) at (5,5) {$a_3$};
        \node [dot] (k) at ($(j) + (270:1)$) {};
        \node [dot] (l) at ($(k) + (270:0.5)$) {};
        \node [dot] (m) at ($(l) + (270:0.5)$) {};
        \node[draw, ellipse, label=below:$A$, fit=(h) (i) (j) (k) (l) (m)] {};

        \path (h) edge [-stealth, auto, swap] node {$w_1$} (a)
                  edge [-stealth, auto] node[below, sloped] {$w_2$} (e)
            (i) edge [-stealth, auto, swap] node {$w_3$} (b)
            (j) edge [-stealth, auto] node[below, sloped] {$w_4$} (a)
                  edge [-stealth, auto] node[above, sloped] {...} (f)
              (k) edge [-stealth, auto] node[above, sloped] {...} (c)
              (l) edge [-stealth, auto] node[below, sloped] {...} (d)
              (m) edge [-stealth, auto] node {...} (f);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{A graph $G$}
\end{figure}
```

Any suggestion how it can be fixed?

I am using Springer LNCS document class, if that makes any difference.

Comment: Does the page with the figure happen to be the very last page by any chance?  I think once you add additional text, things will work fine.  Also, please always post  a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and all the appropriate packages.

Comment: I try your code with svmult.cls of springer without problem. I place the figure between two `\lipsum`. You need to give us a real MWE that illustrates the problem.

Comment: I removed the "thanks" from your question. This is just the style here, intended to keep the questions neat. Thanks is best expressed as upvoting answers that help you. In addition, your question is unlikely to be solved without the MWE. Please provide it for us so we can find a solution without having to guess what packages and macros you're using.

Comment: hey guys, apologies for not supplying a MWE for this one. It turns out Peter Grill is right that once additional text is added after the figure, the problem fixes itself. So there wasn't actually a problem with my document or the Tikz figure. Thanks.

Comment: @PeterGrill, just out of curiosity, how to make a figure align at the top of a new page if the figure just happens to be the only thing on the very last page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the figure happens to be on the very last page with no text following it it is centered as illustrated by the MWE below (if you comment out the `\setlength` line).

As per [Vertical layout of float pages](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-vertposfp) the values that control the distances between floats are:

> `\@fptop` defines the distance from the top of the page to the top of the first float,

> `\@fpsep` defines the separation between floats, and

> `\@fpbot` defines the distance from the bottom of the last float on the page to the bottom of the page.

and the default values are:

```
\@fptop = 0pt + 1fil
\@fpsep = 8pt + 2fil
\@fpbot = 0pt + 1fil
```

So, setting `\@fptop` to something without the `1fill`, achieves the desired result.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% Remove [demo] option in real use
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter% Set distance from top of page to first float
\setlength{\@fptop}{5pt}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]
\begin{figure}[ht!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{foo}
    \caption{A graph $G$}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is an answer to the extension of my original question (see comments above). Thanks!